# How to remove top margin from first <p> paragraph after <h2> and top margin from <h2> when it comes after <p>?

Tags: css

How to top margin from first `<p>` paragraph after `<h2>`? and if any `h2` comes after `p` then either `p` should not have bottom margin or `h2` should not have top margin

I have

```
h2
p

h2
p
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to remove top margin from first `<p>` paragraph after `<h2>`?

Use this:

```
h2 + p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

`+` is the 
[adjacent sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector). It's supported in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

> if any h2 comes after p then either p should not have bottom margin or
>   h2 should not have top margin

Using `+` again in exactly the same way..

```
p + h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

You can even combine them:

```
h2 + p, p + h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I also want if any `h2` comes after `p` then either `p ` should not have bottom margin or `h2` should not have top margin

Comment: Sneaky Jitendra, it was a `h1` before. Thanks @BoltClock.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: You should have mentioned that in your original question.

Comment: Yes actually it was `h2` in hurry i typed `h1` then edited later but your answer applies to both so no issue

Comment: @BoltClock - Should i edit this question now or should ask new question?

Answer (score 2):

Use this selector:

```
h2 + p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: i want after h1 + p:last-child css

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<h1>Some header</h1>
<p class='noTop'>Some paragraph content</p>
```

and then in your css you write

```
.noTop{
 margin-top:0px;
}
```

And then for every p you place under a h1 you can add the class noTop (or another class of your choice)

Comment: This is the most cross platform safe solution. It is also versatile for other situations. Adding meaningful classes to objects is the best way to manage styles. Keep the style separate from the content and the  scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to it, say block

CSS:

```
.block{
enter code here
```